# How to copy cell styles from multiple input xlsx files to multiple output xlsx files with multiple sheets

Tags: python-3.x, formatting, openpyxl

The input files will be taken from a folder to combined/split it. The output file/s will be put in an output folder.
I used openpyxl to copy the styles from the input to output, but it just overwrites the same index of the output files.
Here is the code:

```
    input_file_loc = [x for x in os.listdir(path1) if x.endswith(".xlsx")]
    output_file_loc = [y for y in os.listdir(path2) if y.endswith(".xlsx")]
    
        n = 0
        for i in output_file_loc:
            wb2 = load_workbook(f"{path2}/" + output_file_loc[n])
            ws2 = wb2.active
            n += 1

        filecount = 0
        for i in input_file_loc:
            wb1 = load_workbook(f"{path1}/" + input_file_loc[filecount])

            for sheet in wb1.sheetnames:
                ws1 = wb1[sheet]        
                for r in ws1.rows:
                    for c in r:
                        ws2[c.coordinate] = c.value
                        ws2cell = ws2[c.coordinate]
                        if c.has_style:
                            ws2cell.font = copy(c.font)
                            ws2cell.font = copy(c.font)
                            ws2cell.border = copy(c.border)
                            ws2cell.fill = copy(c.fill)
                            ws2cell.number_format = copy(c.number_format)
                            ws2cell.alignment = copy(c.alignment)
            wb2.save(f"{path2}/output.xlsx")     # save output file/s
            filecount += 1
```

Comment: What's the difference between this question and your previous one?

Comment: its basically the same. but i am still trying to figure out openpyxl on how to append the files below the existing file. at the moment , it just overwrites the same row lines.x

Comment: i manage to read all the sheets from the input files. but i think the index of the inputs are the reason that the output is overwitten. and that is the problem i need to solve